# drupal 7: how to add a field that displays a message when user is not logged in?

Tags: entities

I need a way to set up a field available only for logged in users. When anonymous user reach the page that contains this field, drupal must display a message that request to hte user to login or register to display this field. This is the same that appens for comments. There is a module that impelments this for single fields?

Comment: What about showing a block only to anonymous users on pages that contain the field?  Would that work?

Comment: You need a normal entity field that only displays for logged in users and if the user is not logged in it should display a message instead, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following 2 modules: [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) and [Markup](https://www.drupal.org/project/markup).

1. Define the field.
2. Directly behind, define the markup field that shows the message to log in.
3. Use field permissions to allow access to the target field for authenticated users only.
4. Use field permissions to allow access to the markup field for anonymous users only.

That workaround should solve you issue.